# Какое обращение к полям правильнее и менее ресурсозатратно

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите, какое обращение и изменение поля правильнее и менее ресурсозатратно: к статическому полю или к условно такому же полю, но через экземпляру класса. Или разницы никакой нет.

Comment: Внутри экземляра быстрее работают поля экземляра. За пределами экземляра статика и нестатика +- одинаково. А вообще избегайте статики там где возможно.

Comment: @aepot, благодарю за ответ!